# Set and get value with enum as a key in map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, enums

So what I want to do is mapping my enum to a pointer to an object. This is my current code:

```
  enum state {A,B,C};

class imageTexture {
public:
    imageTexture(std::string path) {};
};

int main() {
    std::map<state, imageTexture*> theMap;
    theMap[A] = new imageTexture("a");

    return 0;
}
```

Online version : http://ideone.com/v9HA4h

This is the place where it stops working. The full error is:

> no viable overloaded operator[] for map

I have done some research on this and I found something with constant but I could get through this error well. I have also looked through some example code for map and get more confused:

```
std::map<string, int> theMap;
theMap['A'] = 1;
```

This is the same as what I have done but mine is not working. Can someone help me out? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Edit: Update the part of the code where I have the problem

Edit 2: I tried the code online and it works. However, it doesn't in my laptop. Would it just the problem of my compiler not working with c++11?

Comment: @juanchopanza fixed :). Thanks :)

Comment: Can the downvoter tell me what's wrong? Or is it because of the code, since I have fixed it

Comment: @TreeNguyen do you mean that this solved your problem?

Comment: Your code is full of typos. You should make an MCVE and post the error you get too. We cannot guess which one of the many errors is the one you care about, and which ones you introduced just for fun.

Comment: you should not fix the code in the question. If you do that you could as well delete the question. The best would be to undo your edit and post the corrected code as answer. Just in case you doubt: Yes you can answer your own question and if you like your answer you can even accept it.

Comment: @TreeNguyen what do you think `enum state = {A,B,C};` does?

Comment: @PhillipD ah no. Before I have map[A] instead of theMap[A] :). Fixed it :D

Comment: In case performance (or space) ever becomes an issue, it's worth pointing out that for enums, which are basically ints, you might as well just use an array or a vector (provided you're good about using contiguous values). Then you'll have way better cache locality + performance.

Comment: @tobi303 it's typo in my code

Comment: @user2079303 create a state type as enum, which has 3 different values A,B and C

Comment: @TreeNguyen but if I understood correctly, after fixing the typo the error message (and thus the purpose of the question) is gone...

Comment: @tobi303 no. I just incorrectly type the code up here. Everything in my question is fine :)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: @TreeNguyen then I am sorry, my misunderstanding

Comment: @TreeNguyen that's not the syntax for defining an enum type.  Which compiler did you use to compile that successfully?

Comment: Sorry everyone. Fix the code. Have in additional "="

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry. I put in an additional "=" up here. Everything in my code is well-written

Comment: @user2079303 sorry. Have just checked it. I accidentally put an additional "=" in my code up here. The coded in my program is fine

Comment: You keep saying that. Post an MCVE already.

Comment: @TreeNguyen copy the code that reproduces your problem **exactly**. If you *copy* instead of *typing*, then you wouldn't end up with typos and you would have an example that does reproduce the error. Now that you've fixed the typos from the example, it compiles  and runs without any errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c9351197193469e My guess is that your code is actually different from the one you've shown here.

Comment: @user2079303 Hi. I have done the tried the same thing on ideone with simple code and it works. But with the code I have just updated, it doesn't

Comment: @TreeNguyen No you didn`t, see [MCVE].

Comment: That is nowhere near an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TreeNguyen then you've failed to create a mcve. Keep trying. The code that you now posted is useless because you forgot to show the definitions of `imageTexture` and `background`. That said, I'm sure that the code can be simplified in such way that the bug is reproduced without using `imageTexture` or `gRenderer`.

Comment: Conversion from enum to int is implicit so your map should be declared `std::map <int, whatever you want to store>`

Comment: @user2079303 hi. I have tried again :)

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry. I have just fixed it. Could you have a look?

Comment: Please stop wasting everybody's time. Do you realize that your MCVE has no problems?

Comment: @TreeNguyen did you again forget to test if the code reproduces the error? It works fine in here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66e94ea1884d5e58 (except for leaking the memory) edit: and indeed the link to ideone that you posted works too... so there is no problem with your code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review your code or your post, I think that your are missing something important. This code works perfect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum state { RED, YELLOW, GREEN };

class foo
{
    int a;
};


int main()
{
    std::map<state, foo *> theMap;

    theMap[RED] = new foo();

    std::cout << "That's all" << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b73e568aa8074328)

EDITED: It works with C++98 as well (-std=c++98)